# How to render checkbox with label on the side using w2uigrid

Tags: checkbox, grid, label, render, w2ui

I tried using the render property but could not get it to my desired look. 
The code below renders a checkbox only but no label. I need it to have label depends on the text the model will supply. I need the column "Value" to have a dynamic text/caption on the side depending on what is being passed.

```
 @(Html.HeGridHelper("patternTable", "patternGrid").Show(new GridShow
            {
                ToolBar = true,
                Footer = false,
                ToolbarAdd = false,
                ToolbarDelete = false,
                ToolbarEdit = false,
                ToolbarSearch = false,
                ToolbarReload = false,
                ToolbarColumns = false,
                ToolbarSave = false,
                SelectColumn = false

            })

            .Columns(new List<GridColumn>()
            {

                    new GridColumn {Caption="ID", Field = "recid", Size = "0%", Hidden = true, Hideable = false, Sortable = false, Resizable = false },
                    new GridColumn { Caption ="", Field = "Value" , Min = 50, Size = "25%",  Editable = new EditableCheck {}},
                    new GridColumn { Caption = CommunityRes.Order, Field = "Order", Min = 50, Size = "25%",  Editable = new EditableText {  } , Render="<label> 'test'</label>"},
                    new GridColumn { Caption = CommunityRes.Suffix, Field = "Sfx", Min = 50, Size = "25%",  Editable = new EditableText {  } },

            }).ToHtmlString())
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. The grid column should look like this: The Editable part is not important coz it is being ignored by the render.

```
    new GridColumn { Caption ="", Field = "Value" , Min = 50, Size = "25%",  Editable = new EditableCheck {},  Render = "function (record) { return ( record.Value ? '<input type=checkbox checked/>'  + '&nbsp' + '<label>' + record.Name + '</label>'  : '<input type=checkbox />'  + '&nbsp' + '<label>' + record.Name + '</label>') }"},
```